# sharedpreferences.getInt() giving default values when called in another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I created a shared preference in one activity. The value is getting stored but when I try to access it in another activity it just returns the default value. Any idea what is wrong with my code?

activity 1:

```
        public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
        public static final String Monday = "monkey";
        public static final String Tuesday = "tuekey";
        public static final String Wednesday = "wedkey";
        public static final String Thursday = "thukey";
        public static final String Friday = "frikey";
        public static final String Saturday = "satkey";
        public static final String Sunday = "sunkey";



            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);   

      String start = ed_start.getText().toString();
            String end = ed_end.getText().toString();

            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            int dd1 = Integer.parseInt(start.substring(0, 2));
            int mm1 = Integer.parseInt(start.substring(3, 5));
            int yy1 = Integer.parseInt(start.substring(6,8));
            c1.set(yy1, mm1, dd1);


            Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            int dd2 = Integer.parseInt(end.substring(0, 2));
            int mm2 = Integer.parseInt(end.substring(3, 5));
            int yy2 = Integer.parseInt(end.substring(6,8));
            c2.set(yy2, mm2, dd2);

            int mon = 0;
            int tue = 0;
            int wed = 0;
            int thu = 0;
            int fri = 0;
            int sat = 0;
            int sun = 0;
            c2.add(Calendar.DATE,1);

            while(c2.after(c1)) {
                if(c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.MONDAY)
                    mon++;
                if(c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.TUESDAY)
                    tue++;
                if(c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.WEDNESDAY)
                    wed++;
                if(c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.THURSDAY)
                    thu++;
                if(c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.FRIDAY)
                    fri++;
                if(c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.SATURDAY)
                    sat++;
                if(c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.SUNDAY)
                    sun++;
                c1.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
            }

              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(Start, start);
            editor.putString(End,end);
            editor.putInt(Monday,mon);
            editor.putInt(Tuesday,tue);
            editor.putInt(Wednesday,wed);
            editor.putInt(Thursday,thu);
            editor.putInt(Friday,fri);
            editor.putInt(Saturday,sat);
            editor.putInt(Sunday,sun);

            editor.commit();
```

activity 2:

```
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String Monday = "monkey";
public static final String Tuesday = "tuekey";
public static final String Wednesday = "wedkey";
public static final String Thursday = "thukey";
public static final String Friday = "frikey";
public static final String Saturday = "satkey";
public static final String Sunday = "sunkey";


        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int k =0;
        int tot = 0;
        for(;k<strings.length;) {
            if(strings[k].equals("Mon")){
                System.out.println("Moday ent");
                System.out.println(sharedPreferences.getInt("Monday",-1 ));
                tot = tot + sharedPreferences.getInt(Monday, 0); }
            if(strings[k].equals("Tue")) {
                System.out.println("tue ent");
                tot = tot + sharedPreferences.getInt(Tuesday,0);}
            if (strings[k].equals("Wed")) {
                System.out.println("wedday ent");
                tot = tot + sharedPreferences.getInt(Wednesday,0); }
            if (strings[k].equals("Thu"))
                tot = tot + sharedPreferences.getInt(Thursday,0);
            if (strings[k].equals("Fri"))
                tot = tot + sharedPreferences.getInt(Friday,0);
            if(strings[k].equals("Sat"))
                tot = tot + sharedPreferences.getInt(Saturday,0);
            if (strings[k].equals("Sun"))
                tot = tot + sharedPreferences.getInt(Sunday, 0);
            k = k+4;
        }
        System.out.println("tot: " + tot);
        tot = (int)((float)tot*(per/100));
```

Comment: Is `MyPREFERENCES` the same in both cases?

Comment: what are the values monday, tuesday etc. where You pass Your values on sharedPreferences? it´s not posted

Comment: @Opiatefuchs : added them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you enter your values to the `SharedPrefs` you need to use the key-value format, meaning the key needs to be in quotation marks.. as follows:

```
editor.putString("Start", start);
```

You did not use quotation marks...

same when you retrieve it back in your `getInt()` (you have done it correctly there..)

Good luck!

EDIT:

In your 1st Activity you gave Constant key values that are equal to: "monkey", "tuekey" and so on.

In your 2nd Activity you are calling them with key values of "Monday", Tuesday" and so on.
Therefore the values are different and you are getting default values

Comment: no, You don´t need it. If You declare a string variable like private String Monday = "Monday"; , You can use it

Comment: So, it should be a comment.

Comment: @jungleboy No. My answer was based on code he posted. If it was not posted it could be a mistake he made and that could be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You set Your values for the sharedPreferences like this:

```
          public static final String Monday = "monkey";
    public static final String Tuesday = "tuekey";
    public static final String Wednesday = "wedkey";
    public static final String Thursday = "thukey";
    public static final String Friday = "frikey";
    public static final String Saturday = "satkey";
    public static final String Sunday = "sunkey";
```

and retrieve them with

```
    "Monday"
    "Tuesday"
    "Wednesday"
       .
       .
      etc
```

This values have to be equal. So You have to retrieve them for example like this:

```
    sharedPreferences.getInt("monkey",0);}
```

or You have to set the values in Your activity like:

```
    public static final String Monday = "Monday";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your keys are wrong: activity 1

```
 public static final String Monday = "monkey";
```

activity 2:

```
if(strings[k].equals("Mon")){
            System.out.println("Moday ent");
            System.out.println(sharedPreferences.getInt("Monday",-1 ));
            tot = tot + sharedPreferences.getInt("Monday", 0); }
```

See this line:

```
getInt("Monday",-1 ));
```

It should be :

```
getInt("monkey",-1 ));//similarly for all the fields
```

As you are using public static final String for all the keys you can use :

```
ClassName.MONDAY //this is what I always do no chance for key errors
```

Comment: its illegal argument by the way lol change it throughout the code. You have a whole lot of values in sharedpreference. try Activity1.Monday in second activity